# To which app services do I deploy

Tags: azure, deployment

Maybe this is a stupid question, but to which app service do I deploy my code to?

The Sitecore Azure Toolkit has deployed XP Scaled with the following Web Apps

- foobar-acc-cd
- foobar-acc-cm
- foobar-acc-ma-ops
- foobar-acc-ma-rep
- foobar-acc-prc
- foobar-acc-rep
- foobar-acc-xc-collect
- foobar-acc-xc-refdata
- foobar-acc-xc-search

This has given me a bit of an option paralysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would deploy your main Sitecore application code to the Content Management and the Content Delivery app instances. Based on your list that would be:

- foobar-acc-cd
- foobar-acc-cm

If you do have any custom code for processing xDB data, you may also need to deploy to the processing instance, which looks like

- foobar-acc-prc

in your list.

#### Update from comments:

As mentioned in the comments below, there are scenarios where you might need to deploy models/dlls to the xConnect services too.

Comment: Worth mentioning that there are common scenarios where you will also need to deploy models and DLL's to the xConnect roles too.

Comment: For Example adding custom facets results in deployment to xconnect and ma instances -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deploy-a-custom-model.html